# How to find attribute in array of elements

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I have two arrays one of them is input elements array and other one is array of attributes. I want to find attribute using attributes array in each element of elements array If found then create new array of available attributes in each element.

**Elements Array**

```
(2) [input#hotel_name_input.valid.form-control, select#select_company.valid.form-control]
0: input#hotel_name_input.valid.form-control
1: select#select_company.valid.form-control
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**Attributes Array**

```
var validAttrs = ["required", "minlength", "maxlength", "lettersonly"];
```

**Required Array**

```
[
  ["required", "minlength"],
  ["maxlength", "lettersonly"]
];
```

**Code**

```
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];

$.each(InputElementsArr, function(a, b)
{
    $.each(InputElementsArr[a].attributes, function(k, v){
        var a = v.name;
        $.each(validAttrs, function(e, m)
        {
            if(a == m)
            {
                arr1.push(a);
            }
        });
    });
        arr2.push(arr1);
});

console.log(arr2);
```

I am not getting desired result, please guide where I am wrong

Comment: Can you add the HTML and create a snippet to test your code please ? And why do you do `InputElementsArr[a].attributes` in your second `$.each`?   `InputElementsArr[a] = b` no ? a is 0 and 1 and b is the selector no ?

Comment: I am searching all available attributes in each element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to initialize arr1 inside the first loop. This ensures that we get a clean slate for each element. Also, there is no need for the 3rd loop. Just use array method of `indexOf` to check if an element exists.

```
$.each(InputElementsArr, function(a, b)
{
    arr1 = [];
    $.each(InputElementsArr[a].attributes, function(k, v){
        var a = v.name;
        if(validAttrs.indexOf(a) >= 0){
            arr1.push(a);
        }
    });
    arr2.push(arr1);
});

console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter workaround

```
validAttrs.map(attr => {

   var a = [];
   InputElementsArr.forEach(ele => {
        if (ele.attributes.indexOf(attr) >= 0)
            a.push(attr);                
   })

   return a;
})
```